# URL-based debug mode

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfadmin

ColdFusion's documentation states

> Another option available is to use a URL parameter mode=debug. The URL
>   would look like this www.allaire.com?mode=debug. This URL will display
>   debug information whether you have debug information turned on or off
>   in the administrator.

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-debug-information-using-mode.html

The documentation does not list the ColdFusion version number and it does not seem to work in CF 9.01.

Does this still work? (It sounds like a security risk)

Comment: Funnily enough [that URL](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-debug-information-using-mode.html) is returning a 404 page now

Comment: It can be seen at https://web.archive.org/web/20120327062555/http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-debug-information-using-mode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that is just old documentation. You are correct, that is a HUGE security risk.

I found [this reference](http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vuln/HTTP_ColdFusion_Debug.htm) and [this reference](http://xforce.iss.net/xforce/xfdb/6792) related to ColdFusion 4.5

I found [this reference](https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/http-cf-0002) related to ColdFusion 5.0

And [here is some old documentation](http://www.houseoffusion.com/cfdocs1/Developing_Web_Applications_with_ColdFusion/24_Debugging_and_Troubleshooting/dwa24_1.htm) with it as well, from the Allaire days.

I am also running ColdFusion 9.0.1 and adding `?mode=debug` to the URL does nothing.

Comment: That sounds crazy .. IIRC the admin settings trump all in most recent versions. Of course it does say "wwww.allaire.com", so I vote for *very* "outdated" documentation ;-)

Comment: @Leigh I had to laugh when I found that one. Adobe is notorious for carrying forward their documentation without changing anything. I'm still trying to find any mention of when they disabled this functionality.

Comment: Yeah, but ... "Allaire"?! Haha, I would say that is carrying bad habits just a little too far.

Comment: Funny - I heard Jeremy Allaire testify before congress the other day. I said, "hey... I almost know that guy!" :)